# how to add JPanel from another class to JFrame in BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I refer to "Add JPanel from another class to JFrame in another class", but this layout manager is Flowlayout. I want to add JPanel from another class in "BorderLayout", and my code is not working. Am I not doing well? What did I miss?

This is my code.

**Main.java**

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welcome, Hot Coffee!!");

    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,400);
        setVisible(true);

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        welcome.setOpaque(true);
        welcome.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        welcome.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        c.add(welcome, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(new Bottom(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        c.add(new Coffee(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

**Bottom.java**

Here, I did many methods like setOpaque, create new JPanel, and so on. I delete that, because it doesn't working, I delete that.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Bottom extends JPanel {
    public Bottom() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setOpaque(true);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Black Coffee");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Sugar Coffee");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("Dabang Coffee");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("Reset");

        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
        add(btn3);
        add(btn4);
    }
}
```

coffee.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Coffee extends JPanel {
    public Coffee(){
       //todo
   }
}
```

Comment: `setVisible(true)` should be at the end of the constructor, when construction is completed.

Comment: Oh, I also did it at the end of Bottom(), and it doesn't work... did I put it wrong? @c0der

Comment: I guess by "not working", you mean "doesn't compile". That's (maybe among other things) because Your Coffee constructor is misspelled `coffee` instead of `Coffee`. If you mean something else, then post the **actual** code, and tell **precisely** what the problem is.

Comment: After adding a component there is a need to repaint and validate (re run layout mangers). If you manually force repaint and validate (for example by resizing the frame) `Bottom` should show up.  Putting `setVisible(true)` at the end of the `JFrame` constructor will take care of that.

Comment: @JB Nizet Ah, It's not about spelling. There's no problem with compile and That's my all code. I think bottom panel is 'not showing' is more precisely.

Comment: You were already been told twice that setVisible(true) must be at the end of the constructor. It's still at the beginning. Put it at the end.

Comment: @c0der Wow! I move `setVisible(true) at the end of the JFrame and working! I've been holding it for two days, and I feel empty.... THank you very much

Comment: Oh that was the point I was missing and I misunderstood because of the same name. Thank you for your help @JB Nizet